# Import Emails from specific folder in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm currently using the following code in Excel to access folders in an unmanned Outlook mailbox other than my own.

However is there a way I can set the folder in the code rather than using the folder picker.

```
Sub Launch_Pad()   
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder

n = 2
Cells.ClearContents

Call ProcessFolder(olFolder)

Set olNS = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(olfdStart As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olObject As Object
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
   n = 1
For Each olObject In olfdStart.Items
    If TypeName(olObject) = "MailItem" Then

        n = n + 1
        Set olMail = olObject
            Cells(n, 1) = olMail.Subject
            Cells(n, 2) = olMail.ReceivedTime
            Cells(n, 3) = olMail.Body

    End If
Next
Set olMail = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Great just what i was looking for !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Erdem

```
Sub ShareMail()

    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("mail@mail.com")
    Set olFolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("myfolder")

   Call ProcessFolder(olFolder)

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olRecip = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the folder should be the inbox you can use below

```
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Or for a subfolder

```
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("mysubfolder")
```

Comment: Thanks but this only works on folders in own inbox and not on the other mailbox listed along side my own

Comment: Try `Set olFolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("mysubfolder")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Work with *[GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220116%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)* to get access to another user for one or more of their default folders.

Example here is shared Inbox

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@EmailAddress.com")
Set olFolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)

Or

Set olFolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("SubfolderName")
```

---

> <sub>*[GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220116%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  Returns a `MAPIFolder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).*</sub>

Comment: Thx, I can access the inbox but how would I access a sub folder