# shared inbox how do you get vba to go there instead of my own inbox

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, default, inbox

**`Set inboxFolder = outNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`**

this bit goes to my default inbox but i have a shared inbox how would i get it to take the emails from there . any suggestions be great i have tried a few things my self but no success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43274164/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Use either `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` or (if the mailbox is already open in the current profile), use `Namespace.Store` collection to find the right store, then use `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.